# Normal derivative expressed in polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

A normal derivative on a given contour $\Gamma$ of a function $u$ expressed in Cartesian coordinates $u=u(x,y)$, can be calculated as:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = \nabla u \cdot n = 
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} n_x + 
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} n_y
$$ 
where symbols are depicted in the figure.

[image]

When a segment of a curve is parametrized by normalized variable $\xi \in [-1,1]$ we can describe its geometry as:

$x=x(\xi)= \sum_i x_i N_i(\xi)$        and 
$y=y(\xi)= \sum_i y_i N_i(\xi)$

where $(x_i, y_i)$ are nodal points, and $N_i$ - interpolation polynomials, e.g. Lagrange polynomials. 
This leads to the derivatives:

$\frac{dx}{d\xi}= \sum_i x_i \frac{dN_i}{d\xi}$ and 
$\frac{dy}{d\xi}= \sum_i y_i \frac{dN_i}{d\xi}$

The Jacobian of the transformation between local and global coordinates can be calculated as

$$d\Gamma = \sqrt{dx^2+dy^2} $$

and the components of the normal vector are equal

$n_x = \cos \alpha = \frac{dy}{d\Gamma}$

$n_y = - \sin \alpha = -\frac{dx}{d\Gamma}$

In this way one can describe components of the normal vector in terms of Cartesian coordinates and consequently in terms of parameter $\xi$.

Now what if the function $u$ and a curve $\Gamma$ are expressed in polar coordinates
$r = r(\theta)$, $\theta = [0,2\pi]$, $u=u(r,\theta)$? Recently, some paper that I found provided the following formula: $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} - \frac{r'}{r^2} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}.$$

According to the theory the normal derivative in polar coordinates is given by:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = \nabla u \cdot n = 
\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} n_r + 
\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta} n_\theta
$$ 
and what I need is to express the radial and angular components of the normal vector in terms of polar coordinates, or in fact in terms of parameter $\theta$ because $r=r(\theta)$. 
Taking into account that
$x=r(\theta) \cos \theta$,
$y=r(\theta) \sin \theta$ and
$d\Gamma = \sqrt{dx^2+dy^2} $
it can be obtained that
$$d\Gamma = \sqrt{r'^2 + r^2} $$
but I can't find any trigonometric relations between $dr$, $d\theta$ and  $n_r$, $n_\theta$ as it can be found for $dx$, $dy$, $n_x$, $n_y$. So my question is: Could anyone provide formulae for $n_r$ and $n_\theta$ in terms of polar coordinates?

**EDIT**: 
I found [another paper](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Chein_Shan_Liu/publication/264421370_A_highly_accurate_MCTM_for_inverse_Cauchy_problems_of_Laplace_equation_in_arbitrary_plane_domains/links/53dddebf0cf2a76fb667cca7.pdf?ev=pub_ext_doc_dl&origin=publication_detail&inViewer=true) which contains formula that I was looking for. It is different from the formula from formerly cited paper by the same author. What is more, it is a bit different from what Ted Schifrin derived.

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = 
\frac{r}{\sqrt{r'^2 + r^2}}
\left[ \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} - \frac{r'}{r^2} 
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta} \right]
$$

The appendix of the paper gives the derivation of the formula. Now everything seems OK to me.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the source?

Comment: [Here it is](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/229221818_An_effectively_modified_direct_Trefftz_method_for_2D_potential_problems_considering_the_domain%27s_characteristic_length). Eq. (3)

Comment: So, you've edited partially. Your first equation should be written as follows: $$\nabla u = \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\hat r + \frac1r\frac{\partial u}{\partial\theta}\hat\theta$$ (or, if you can prefer, you can write $e_r,e_\theta$ for the unit vectors). The formula for the normal derivative is something totally different. It's not a matter of "this can be derived as ...".

Comment: Maybe you're trying to write that the normal derivative is given by $\nabla u\cdot n$, and then $n_r$ and $n_\theta$ represent the *components* of $n$ with respect to the orthonormal basis $\hat r,\hat\theta$?

Comment: That is right. This is what I mean by $n_r$ and $n_\theta$

Answer (score 2):

The contour at hand is assumed to be given by $r=r(\theta)$.

**EDIT**: OK, I've tried to decipher what's going on here. I presume that the article you cite is referring to the normal derivative along a level (contour) curve of $u$. The formula does not seem to be correct with my guess that the author is parametrizing the curve by $r=r(\theta)$. With that assumption, I get the formula
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = \frac{r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}-r'\frac{\partial u}{\partial\theta}}{\sqrt{r^2 + r'^2}}=\frac{\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}-\frac{r'}r\frac{\partial u}{\partial\theta}}{\sqrt{1 + \big(\frac{r'}r\big)^2}}.$$

Comment: The formula coresponding to (2) in the cited paper also has a "-" sign in front of the $(r'/r^2) (\partial u/\partial \theta)$ term.

Comment: Indeed, there is this minus sign in the paper and there was this minus in my first post. I've corrected the formula. Hope the editors won't "revise" it again :-)

Comment: @ Ted Shifrin During Christmas days I had my time to think about the problem once again. I have edited my first post.  Unfortunately I'm unable to obtain any of the given solutions.  Can I ask you to give me some more hints?